# How to pass the xml to web service and get back the json reply

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
url: '<spring:url value="/service/org/fixt/assignlist"/>',      
    mtype: "POST",
    postData: fxXML,
    datatype: "json",
    autoencode: true,
```

I am able to post xml using ajax call and get the reply back in json format. But now I don't know how to post this xml to the web service and get the json back using jqgrid.

Comment: For one, your sticking XML in a parameter that only accepts arrays according to the documentation (though what the documentation refers to as an array is really an object...)

Comment: What should I do achieve it then , my web service accepts the xml and returns the json

Comment: I dont want to pass as a parameter , I want to pass it as a POST data

Comment: I don't know, i've never worked with jqGrid. I expected to see a "source" option but I can't find it.

Comment: From where did you get the documentation, I have one pdf , but the details are not there in it

Comment: It looks like there's a ajaxGridOptions option where you can pass in ajax options similar to jQuery's $.ajax method. That would allow you to pass in your data the same way you would if you were using $.ajax, you could then omit url mtype postData and datatype

Comment: I'm looking at this documentation: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options